# libgdx rendering a spite

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to render a simple texture with 4 different color squares.There is no error in my syntax.

Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bracco.thrive.ThriveGame.create(ThriveGame.java:21)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:132)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:112)
```

Code

```
package com.bracco.thrive;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.bracco.thrive.world.WorldGeneration;

public class ThriveGame extends Game {

    WorldGeneration wGenerate;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        wGenerate.createWorld();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
     wGenerate.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}


    package com.bracco.thrive.world;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
public class WorldGeneration {

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private int textureWidth,textureHeight;
    private boolean debug = false;
    private Texture texture;



    public void createWorld(){
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
         texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/textures/basictextures.png"));
    }



    public void render(){
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            spriteBatch.begin();
            drawTexture();
            spriteBatch.end();
        }

    private void drawTexture()
    {
        spriteBatch.draw(texture, 0, 16, 0, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: You never instantiate `wGenerate`.

Answer (score 1):

The object of class WorldGeneration is not made.

```
 WorldGeneration wGenerate;

@Override
public void create() {      
wGenerate=new WorldGeneration();

    wGenerate.createWorld();
}
```